# How can I create a query on nested documents?

Tags: mongodb, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to find a document inside nested collection, but I do not know how should I create query for this. In **TypeORM** documentation there is only one simple example how to use `find/findOne` on not nested documents.

I created this query:

```js
const result: BlogEntity = await this.blogRepository.findOne({posts: {_id: article._id}});
```

but when I am trying to build my project i am getting this error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type '{ posts: { _id: ObjectID; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | Date | ObjectID | FindOneOptions | Partial'.

After this i also tried :

```js
const result: BlogEntity = await this.blogRepository.findOne({posts: {_id: article._id}});
const result: BlogEntity = await this.blogRepository.findOne({'posts._id':  article._id});
const result: BlogEntity = await this.blogRepository.findOne({where: {posts: { _id: article._id}}});
const result: BlogEntity = await this.blogRepository.findOne({where: {'posts._id': _id: article._id}});
const result: ArticleEntity = await this.mongoManager.findOne(ArticleEntity, {_id: article._id});
```

But none of them is working

So the question is how should i correctly create this find query. **BlogEntity** and **ArticleEntity** code bellow

**BlogEntity**

```js
@Entity()
@ObjectType()
export class BlogEntity {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @ObjectIdColumn()
  _id!: ObjectID;

  @Field(() => [ArticleEntity])
  @Column()
  posts!: ArticleEntity[];

  @Field(() => [ArticleEntity])
  @Column()
  projects!: ArticleEntity[];

  @Field(() => [ArticleEntity])
  @Column()
  tutorials!: ArticleEntity[];
}
```

**ArticleEntity**

```js
@Entity()
@ObjectType()
export class ArticleEntity {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @ObjectIdColumn()
  _id!: ObjectID;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  title!: string;

  @Field(() => [String])
  @Column()
  tags!: string[];

  @Field()
  @Column()
  release!: Date;

  @Field(() => [SectionEntity])
  @Column()
  sections!: SectionEntity[];

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  @Column()
  tutorial?: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  @Column()
  app?: string;
}
```

If you need anything else ping me in the comment section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it is impossible to achive this in TypeORM. The only one solution which I see there is to swich to **Typegoose** or **Mongoose**.
If you are more interested in this issue you can read more here: [Issue: Query an Array of Embedded Documents #2483](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2483)

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with `nested object's` you need to use `(.)` operator

```
await this.blogRepository.findOne({'posts._id': article._id});
```

Comment: Yes it will actually work but I need to add ```@ts-ignore``` to avoid typescript errors and I will also get whole **Blog Entity** Object with lists of ```posts```, ```projects``` and ```tutorials``` and it is not something what I am looking for. Is there any possibilty to get only this one post ?